# OpenNMS Http data collector with form authentication

Tags: java, opennms

I am new to openNMS, and using Http collector to     collect data from particualar web page, My server need basic form based authentication, first i have to give my UserName/password and if it is authenticated then it will take me to Home page from where i need to read some data from Html page.
 Just let you know i tried to find out this issue in OpenNMS documentation and followed link http://www.opennms.org/wiki/HTTP_Collector but its without any authentication and  don't provide any information for authentication.
Any one is having any idea..how to do the same if i need authenticate the login page first and after successful login, read text from the home page (which is next page)...A little help or suggestion will be appreciated.

Thanks
Tapan

Answer (score 1):

see http://www.opennms.org/wiki/AfHttpCollector

```
        <uri>
            <url user-info="USERNAME:PASSWORD" host="${ipaddr}" http-version="1.1" matches="(?s).*BytesPerSec:\s([0-9]+).*BusyWorkers:\s([0-9]+).*IdleWorkers:\s([0-9]+).*" path="/monitoring/server-status/" port="443" query="auto" response-range="100-399" scheme="https"/>
            <attributes>
                    <attrib alias="SBytesPerSec" match-group="1" type="gauge32"/>
                    <attrib alias="SBusyWorkers" match-group="2" type="gauge32"/>
                    <attrib alias="SIdleWorkers" match-group="3" type="gauge32"/>
            </attributes>
        </uri>
```

Note that the example is for HTTPS.

Comment: Curses, my reference to Reading The Full Manual was removed!